# Installing MySQLdb python 2.7 64bit

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I cannot find a way to install the correct version of MySQL-python (Windows, 64 bit). Is there a simple installer available anywhere? I have tried from:

http://www.codegood.com/archives/129

But when I try import MySQLdb in my IDE I get the error:

```
ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 4, 'beta', 4), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
```

which I do not understand and doesn't really explain what I need to do to resolve the issue

I'm hosting the server on Amazon Web Service RDS

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on factors like where you are hosting the database and how you want to connect it. Check out the MySQL Developer Guide for how to access version number checks and connectivity trouble shooting: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/

Comment: I'm hosting the db on Amazon Web Server RDS. I'll read through that link

Comment: Amazon has their own way of establishing databases. How are you connecting to your live environment (Beanstalk, S3, etc?)

Comment: Even this (which i presume is very basic) is above my head. I'm going to try and find a very basic tutorial

Answer (score 0):

First try to download the python mysql connector from website (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)
And then try to install the mysql version which supports the connector.